# Tkinter combobox output data in entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been working on this little Tkinter address book system.
The system is such that, it has a combobox and an entry. I am pulling data from the database to the entry.

Here's the catch, I want the entry to give me the telephone number of the name I selected from the combobox. I picked someones function from here, changed a few things and it still gives me a different output.

Here is the output it gives in the entry:

```
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x102e09f10>
```

And here is the code.

```
class MyListbox:
   def __init__(self, parent, title):
      self.parent = parent
      self.parent.title(title)
      self.parent.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.closes)
       data = cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM addressbook')
       self.myData = data
       self.establishment()

   def combobox_handler(self, event):
       current = self.combobox.current()
       self.entNumber.delete(0, END)
       self.entNumber.insert(END, self.myData)


   def establishment(self):
       mainFrame = Frame(self.parent)
       mainFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

       self.statusBar = Label(mainFrame, text="App",relief=SUNKEN, bd=1)
       self.statusBar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

       fr_left = Frame(mainFrame, bd=10)
       fr_left.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES, side=LEFT)

       names = [person[0] for person in self.myData]
       self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(fr_left, values=names)
       self.combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.combobox_handler)
       self.combobox.pack()

       fr_right = Frame(mainFrame, bd=10)
       fr_right.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES, side=RIGHT)

       fr_up = Frame(fr_right)
       fr_up.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES)

       Label(fr_up, text='Telephone').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
       self.entNumber = Entry(fr_up)
       self.entNumber.grid(row=0, column=1)


   def closes(self, event=None):
       self.parent.destroy()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tell us the result when you select it.

Comment: <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x102602f10>

Comment: This is the result when i select

Comment: the code above doesn't produce such result you can post minimal and complete

Comment: It you reuse 3rd party code here ([especially code taken from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/), but of course limited), be sure to provide required reference.

Answer (score 0):

See this part in your code `current` variable to get the item selected in the `combobox`, you should rather `insert` that in the `entry` widget not `myData` from `sqlite3`.

```
   def combobox_handler(self, event):
       current = self.combobox.current()
       self.entNumber.delete(0, END)
       self.entNumber.insert(END, self.current)
```